# Idea for dealing with link only answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

I particularly think that link-only answers are a plague for several reasons. First before the links can break. I see that administrators generally delete them.

But on the other hand, links can be useful as a kind of reference, or bibliography, like wikipedia does at the end of articles. Links can be a bonus to answers or can help to explain the problem.

So, here is one idea: add a way to add references to questions or answers. References will be links-only. These links will stay on stackexchange and other sites from the family of sites and their servers will scan the links from times to times or links can be scanned every time a page is visited. Every 3 times a link is seen as 404 error it is removed automatically from the links section.

What do you guys think?

Comment: You mean adding another kind of post (in addition to Questions and Answers)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess it means adding yet another, harder to catch kind of backdoor for spam and astroturfing

Comment: @gnat don't think so, and too bad OP can't be bothered to explain.

Comment: thanks everybody down voting this. I was trying to contribute. Down voting is not stimulating people to post here again.

Comment: @SpaceDog You don't understand what votes here at meta mean.  A down vote means people don't agree with you, in other words, they wouldn't find this feature helpful.  Stop worrying so much about down votes.  This idea has not been fully vetted by you, hence the comments, saying you didn't bother to explain

Answer (score 5):

> add a way to add references to questions or answers

There is no need for that. There is already a way to add links to posts and that is by including them in the post itself. Why would you need to add another feature?

I don't see the use of a list of links under a certain post. The post should be informative on its own. Links *support the post*, and thus they have to be placed in it, not next to it. Ideally the link is accompanied with some text and explanation. The post is the ideal place to do so.

Creating extra space for links defeats the goal of SE. We don't want to make SE a link farm, we want useful content.

[Some other ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71529/245360) on handling link rot.